# Load a new WPF Window from a button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have another WPF Window i've created.. say window2.xaml.  I have a button.. and on click i want it to load that window.. i've tried Googling but nothing seems to be working. It just loads a blank page. I know this is really simple, but I really can't find how to do it through my searches.

This is what i have tried:

```
GameClock temp = new GameClock();
temp.ShowDialog();  //just shows blank window
temp.Show();  //just shows a blank window too
```

EDIT: I figured out the problem. I took out the initialize component because there an an error. I thought it was something only the main window needed. When I put it back, it works. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Show your GameClock xaml

Comment: That's basically it. The only thing extra I add is to set the owner: temp.Owner = this; Does your window show in the designer?

Comment: Does the GameClock constructor finish its 'InitializeComponent'?

Comment: ah i messed up... i took out the initializecomponent() cus it was erroring.. put it back in and it worked.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this... u can use like a generic methode

```
private void button_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenWin("window2", new Uri(@"window2.xaml", UriKind.Relative), "Window2Label");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Message.Show(ex);
    }
}

public static DocumentPanel OpenWin(string namePainelItem, Uri xamlPath, string caption = "", RoutedEventHandler unloadEvent = null, bool closeOpenWin = false)
{
    try
    {        
        if (closeOpenWin)
        {
            CloseWin(namePainelItem, false);
        }

        DocumentPanel panel1 = GetWin(namePainelItem);
        if (panel1 == null)
        {
            panel1 = new DocumentPanel();
            panel1.Caption = caption;
            panel1.Name = namePainelItem;
            panel1.Content = xamlPath;

            if (unloadEvent != null)
            {
                panel1.Unloaded += unloadEvent;                        
            }            

            hdl.dockLayoutManager.DockController.Insert(hdl.documentGroup1, panel1, 1);
            hdl.dockLayoutManager.DockController.ActiveItem = panel1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (panel1.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
                panel1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            if(panel1.IsClosed)
                panel1.Closed = false;                    

            hdl.dockLayoutManager.DockController.ActiveItem = panel1;
        }
        return panel1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Message.Show(ex);                
    }
    return new DocumentPanel();
}


public static void CloseWin(string namePainelItem)
{
    try
    {
        BaseLayoutItem item = hdl.dockLayoutManager.GetItem(namePainelItem);

        if (item != null)
        {
            hdl.documentGroup1.Items.Remove(item);
            hdl.dockLayoutManager.DockController.RemovePanel((DocumentPanel)item);
            item = null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Message.Show(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to read the XAML file before creating the instance of GameClock. Something like this:

```
GameClock clock;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
clock = (GameClock)XamlReader.Load(fs);
```

JAB